# How can I change the brightness?

Tags: windows-7, display

I can't find any place where I can control screen brightness.

I did not supply a product key during Windows setup if that matters.

Comment: Have you installed the OS? or is the screen going bad? Connect an external monitor if the screen might be bad. More info needed...

Comment: OS working fine. But some of the features are disabled.

Comment: are you logged on as an admin/power user? UAC window popping up?

Comment: i login as admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options

[image]

you do not have this option? Or are you talking about a hot key? (f2/f3 etc?)

Comment: yes i accept. but i dont have this options in my windows 7. what is the problem? i unable to understand.

Comment: I installed display driver. Problems solved.

Answer (score 3):

Use this Free Software[here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to change you brightness and do lot more things using Command Prompt.

1. Download it and Copy it C: drive.
2. Open command prompt as Admin.
3. Type `cd C:/nircmd`
4. Then `nircmd.exe setbrightness 50`

That value can be from 0 to 100. Check out it documentation for more commands.Enjoy.

Comment: I'd be curious if this works with the default display driver he appears to be using.

Answer (score 2):

That option is missing because after reinstalling windows you didn't reinstall the drivers for your display adapter.

If you're uncertain where to find your driver, post the make and model of your system and someone here I'm sure can post a link to where to download it.